# combining two return of functions of nodejs promise.all not working

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm having two return functions(getMoviesForCSVExport,  getActressesForCSVExport). I want to send those return data into single email as two separate csv attachments.

I'm totally new to nodejs , I tried to call those functions using promise.all. This is what I tried. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
 var arr = [dbGetMovies.getMoviesForCSVExport(search,serviceType,status) ,dbGetMovies.getActressesForCSVExport(search,serviceType,status)];

Promise.all(arr).then(values => { 
   .then((movies) => json2csv({ data: movies, fields: dbGetMovies.WHITE_LISTED_CONTRACTOR_FIELDS}))
   .then((csvData) => emails.sendEmailWithCSVExtract(csvData, tokenPayload.email))
   .then(() => response.setStatusCode(204)) 


});
```

sendEmailWithCSVExtract function below

```
     function sendEmailWithCSVExtract (
  csvData /* :string */,
  emailAddress /* :string */
) /* :Promise<any> */ {
  return getTemplate('./templates/contractor-export.txt')
    .then((template) => mustache.render(template.toString(), { date: moment.utc().add(1, 'days').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY') }))
    .then((messageHtml) => {
      // create Nodemailer SES transporter
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        SES: new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' })
      })

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail({
          from: env('SENDER_EMAIL'),
          to: emailAddress,
          subject: 'CSV Extract Data',
          text: messageHtml,
          attachments: [
            {
              // utf-8 string as an attachment
              filename: 'extract.csv',
              content: csvData
            },
]
          ]
        }, (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error attempting to send email with CSV Extract: ' + err)
            reject(err)
          } else {
            console.log(`CSV extract email sent to: ${emailAddress} (AWS SES MessageId = ${info.messageId})`)
            return resolve(info)
          }
        })
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: "*Please help me to fix this issue.*" - which issue? What does not work? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have invalid syntax and your code will throw at runtime. You can only call `.then()` on a Promise instance. Currently you are calling a method on a non-existing object.

```
Promise.all(arr).then(values => { 
   .then() // .then() of what exactly?
});
```

`Promise.all` resolves with an array of the Promise results which were passed as arguments. In your case that will be an array with two elements like this one: `[moviesForCsvExport, actressesForCsvExport]`. You can access them in the `.then()` callback like this:

```
Promise.all(arr).then((values) => {
  const movies = values[0];
  const actresses = values[1];
});
```

or in a more concise way using array destructuring:

```
Promise.all(arr).then(([movies, actresses]) => {
  // movies and actresses will be available here
});
```

I advice you to read about how Promises work and how to use them because you won't be able to work with them effectively without knowing the basics.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. Yes I need to improve the basic skills. Thanks